# Swift Dictionary of Arrays

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I am making an app that has different game modes, and each game mode has a few scores. I am trying to store all the scores in a dictionary of arrays, where the dictionary's key is a game's id (a String), and the associated array has the list of scores for that game mode. But when I try to initialize the arrays' values to random values, Swift breaks, giving me the error below. This chunk of code will break in a playground. What am I doing wrong?

```
let modes = ["mode1", "mode2", "mode3"]
var dict = Dictionary<String, [Int]>()

for mode in modes
{
    dict[mode] = Array<Int>()
    for j in 1...5
    {
        dict[mode]?.append(j)
        let array:[Int] = dict[mode]!
        let value:Int = array[j]      //breaks here
    }
}
```

ERROR:

```
Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).
```

Comment: It's breaking because array only has one value in it and `j == 1`. In other words, this is an out of bounds error. I am trying to understand your code, and having trouble. Exactly, what is this supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is array subscripts are zero-based.  So when you write:

```
var a: [Int] = []
for i in 1...5 {
    a.append(42)
    println(a[i])
}
```

you will get a runtime error, because first time around the loop you are subscripting `a[1]` when there is only an `a[0]`.  In your code, you either need to do `for j in 0..<5` or `let value = array[j-1]`.

By the way, even though it’s perfectly safe to do `dict[mode]!` (since you just added it), it’s a habit best avoided as one of these days your code won’t be as correct as you think, and that `!` will explode in your face.  There’s *almost* always a better way to write what you want without needing `!`.

Also, generally speaking, whenever you use array subscripts you are risking an accidental screw-up by accidentally addressing an out-of-bounds index like here.  There are lots of alternatives that mean actually using `a[i]` is easy to avoid:

- If you want the indices for a collection (like an array), instead of:

  ```
  for i in 0..<a.count { }
  ```

  you can write

  ```
  for i in indices(a) { }
  ```
- If you want to number the elements in an array, instead of

  ```
  for i in indices(a) { println("item \(i) is \(a[i])" }
  ```

  you can write

  ```
  for (i, elem) in enumerate(a) { println("item \(i) is \(elem)") }
  ```

  If the collection happens to have an `Int` for an index (such as `Array`), you can use `i` as an index, but if it doesn’t (such as `String`) an alternative to get the index and element is:

  ```
  let s = "hello"
  for (idx, char) in Zip2(indices(s),s) { }
  ```
- If you want the first or last element of an array, instead of:

  ```
  if a.count > 0 { let x = a[0] }
  if a.count > 0 { let x = a[a.count - 1] }
  ```

  you can write

  ```
  if let first = a.first { let x = first }
  if let last = a.last { let x = first }
  ```
- Prefer `map`, `filter` and `reduce` to for loops in general (but don’t obsess over it, sometimes a for loop is better)

Comment: Don’t feel stupid we’ve all done it loads of times :).  The moral of this is subscripts can be easy to screw up and there are lots of alternatives (see my edit)